# Very fast and light web call, which technology to use: legacy web service or HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I need some insecure, fast, light and easy to implement web method. Something like this:

```
// Client side
// Parametrize client address which is dynamic and we don't know until run-time
myClient.Address = "http://example.com/method.aspx/?input=" + value;
string result = "";

if (myClient.TryCallWebMethod(out result))
    // Web method succeed. Use returned value.
else
    // Web method failed. No problem, go with plan B.

// Server side
Response.Write("Answer is: " + Request.QueryString[input]);
```

I know this is reconstructing the wheel, but what I need is as simple as above code. I can implement client with `HttpWebRequest` but maybe using a legacy `Web Service` is a better choice.

I have tried `WCF` but there are more choices which I don't need like sessions, security, etc. Also I did a localhost benchmarking and `WCF` came to it's knees at 200 concurrent requests, where I need a support of more than 1000 concurrent calls which is a normal load for an `aspx` page.

This web method is gonna be consumed from a asp.net page. I never used a legacy web service, is it OK for my scenario or like `WCF` it has a dozen of configurations and certificate installations... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the operations provided by `WebClient`, it looks like it just wraps a `HttpWebRequest` functionality and provides extra utility operations. Hence I would suggest you to go for `HttpWebRequest`.

Also on the server side, try to go for a `HttpHandler` instead of aspx page (handlers are light weight)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standard ASPX page you could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var url = "http://example.com/method.aspx?input=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
    string result = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```